# Can a home directory have both .cshrc and .bashrc files?

Tags: bash, csh, bashrc

Or are they both not allowed at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only is it possible, some systems set up new accounts with both. This allows the same skeleton setup to be used whichever shell the user gets.

The purpose of the two file is the same, but they belong to two different shell families.  The syntax of the shell scripts for the two shells is very different so different scripts are required.

With a bit of care it is possible to use the same rc file for Bourne shell, ksh, and bash.  This can be done by inclusion or hard links.

Comment: It can also be done by testing in the rc file for the current shell.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Use of inclusion and hard links can be used when the rc names are different: .shrc. .kshrd, .bashrc, etc.  Testing the for the shell type might be required in some edge case.

Comment: bash, ksh, and zsh will all source `$HOME/.profile`, at least if their shell-specific startup files aren't available.  Having a single `.profile` with shell-specific sections (checking whether `$BASH_VERSION` is set, and so on) might be a reasonable approach if you commonly use two or more Bourne-derived shells.  (I haven't tried that myself.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: The bourne shell variants tend to share profiles but this is not always the case.  The `rc` files usually have different defaults, although there can be configuration options to address this.   Newer shell builds and newer platforms tend to be more likely to have this capability.

Answer (score 11):

Why wouldn't they be?

They're only executed by their respective shells though...

`csh` and `bash` are different programs that happen to do similar functions.